# Insert specific numbers at the end of the values of a column in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, gsub

Let's say I have a data `df` like this:

```
df<-data.frame(date=c(202203,202204,202205,202206))
```

`202203` means March, 2022.
So all the values of `date` column represent year and month .
However, since I don't know the exact date, I want to insert `01` to every values of `date` column.That is ,`202203`should be `20220301`:March 1st,2022 .
My expected output is

```
df<-data.frame(date=c(20220301,20220401,20220501,20220601))
```

I tried to use `gsub` but, the output was not what I have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$date <- as.numeric(paste0(df$date, "01"))
```

oh hang on, got a better one:

```
df$date <- df$date * 100 + 1
```

Comment: Multiplying 100 is a nice idea. I couldn't think that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use paste0 and loop.

For example:

```r
    for(i in df$date){
    
    paste0(i, "01") -> df$date

}
```